# HTML input popup calendar issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pop a calendar control when a user clicks on an input field. The calendar control is actually a div section for calendar which I am trying to toggle the display. The issue is when I click on the input, the calendar does not show up. But the catch is, when I change the position property of input from "relative" to "fixed", then the calendar shows up but relative to the browser. I want it to be displayed relative to the input field.

```
    <script>
    function showCalendar(startDate)
    {
        try{
            //var inputElement = document.getElementById(startDate);
            var inputElement = document.getElementsByName(startDate)[0];
            var divCalendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var divContent = document.getElementById('content');
            if(divCalendar.style.display == 'block')
            {
                divContent.appendChild(divCalendar);
                //inputElement.style.position='fixed';
                //divCalendar.style.position='fixed';
                divCalendar.style.display = 'none';
                //divCalendar.style.zindex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                divCalendar.parentNode.removeChild(divCalendar);
                inputElement.appendChild(divCalendar);
                inputElement.style.position='relative';
                divCalendar.style.position='absolute';
                divCalendar.style.top=30;
                divCalendar.style.left=30;
                //divCalendar.style.zindex = 100;
                divCalendar.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e);
        }

    }
    </script>

        <body>
<div id="content">
        <table id="bookingTable">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4">Book Rentals</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4"><%=fileService.title%></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;">Start Date</td>
                <td style="text-align:left;">
                <input style="cursor:pointer;" type="text" name="startDate" value="" onclick="showCalendar('startDate')">
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">Start Time</td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" name="startTime" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;">End Date</td>
                <td style="text-align:left;">
                <input style="cursor:pointer;" type="text" name="endDate" value="" onclick="showCalendar('endDate')">
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">End Time</td>
                <td style="text-align:left;"><input type="text" name="endTime" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="calendar" style="display: none;">
        Here is create a table dynamically which represent a calendar and which I am trying to toggle the display.
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're also getting other errors : `Cannot read property of type null`

Comment: that is because of this line in JavaScript

   var divContent = document.getElementById('content');

I have not pasted the complete JSP page content here. But basically 'content' is another div element encircling the <table id="bookingTable">

Comment: As a general guideline, on StackOverflow, do not use tabs in your code, or expand them as tabstops are set to 4.  It makes it easier to read the code, in general.

Comment: Does anybody have any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'none')
e.style.display = 'block';
else
e.style.display = 'none';
}
//-->
</script>
```

And this HTML on your button that is toggling the calendar:

```
onClick="toggle_visibility('calendar');"
```

This simply displays/hides the div container with the ID of 'calendar'. You might have to put the calendar script itself inside your div, given that you don't need to pass variables to it via a control.

Comment: No this does not work. But when i wrap the input element with a link <a> and then click on input it works. Here i made <a> parent of div calender and also changed the position of <a> to relative and that of div to absolute.