# popup div when clicked on input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following element my HTML

```
<input style="cursor:pointer;" type="text" name="startDate" value="" onclick="toggle('startDate')"/>
```

I want to show a `<div>` element containing a calender when user click on the above input element. Can anybody help me how to write javascript for this?

I currently wrote a JavaScript with the following piece of code

```
   inputElement.style.position='relative';
   divCalender.style.position='absolute';
   divCalender.style.top=30;
   divCalender.style.left=30;
   divCalender.style.display = 'block';
```

But this does not work for `<input>`. if i write the same JavaScript logic for say `<button>` or `<img>` it works. Can anybody tell me why it does not work for `<input>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML input popup calendar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561317/html-input-popup-calendar-issue) Please do not repost the same question over and over. If you don't get any (satisfying) answers, edit your question to improve it. Editing will bump it back to the top. A better and clearer question will more likely get answers.

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to use DateTime Jquery plugin http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/datetime

(you can modify to only show date)

Comment: Linking to plugins and other tools without providing reasonable information about the question.